# Are ElasticClient.MapRaw and .CreateIndexRaw gone?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

After updating to [NEST](https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST) 0.11.5, it appears as if the `NEST.ElasticClient.MapRaw` and `.CreateIndexRaw` methods aren't supported anymore. Have they been renamed or moved or are they completely gone?

In case they're gone, how can I define custom analysis settings on index creation? This is what I've tried:

```
var indexSettings = new IndexSettings()
    {
        NumberOfReplicas = 1,
        NumberOfShards = 2,
        Analysis = new AnalysisSettings()  // doesn't work, no setter
            {
                // here's where my settings would go...
            }
    };

var response = elasticClient.CreateIndex(indexName, indexSettings);
```

Doesn't work since there's no setter defined for IndexSettings.Analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Raw calls have been pushed down to `elasticClient.Raw.CreateIndexPost(...)`.

For the 0.11.5.0 release i created my own script that scans the elasticsearch source code to generate all the raw calls. Appearantly the elasticsearch dev's have also done this so the `IRawElasticClient` signatures might changes again in the 0.11.6.0 release as NEST will be compatible with the new low level client guidelines.

Also be sure to check out the `MapFluent()` call though

https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest.Tests.Unit/Core/Map/FluentMappingFullExampleTests.cs

And `CreateIndex()` also exposes a fully mapped fluent variant

https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest.Tests.Integration/Indices/Analysis/Analyzers/AnalyzerTests.cs#L19