# Has ElasticClient.TryConnect been removed from NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Here's a code snippet we've used in the past to ping an Elastic Search node, just to check if it's there:

```
Nest.ElasticClient client; // has been initialized
ConnectionStatus connStatus;
client.TryConnect(out connStatus);  
var isHealthy = connStatus.Success;
```

It looks like `ElasticClient.TryConnect` has been removed in [NEST](https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST) 0.11.5. Is it completely gone or has it just been moved to somewhere else [just like MapRaw/CreateIndexRaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363377/are-elasticclient-mapraw-and-createindexraw-gone#19363630)?

In case it's been removed, here's what I'm planning to do instead:

```
Nest.ElasticClient client; // has been initialized
var connectionStatus = client.Connection.GetSync("/");
var isHealthy = connectionStatus.Success;
```

Looks like this works - or is there a better way to replace `TryConnect`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes they have. See the release notes:
https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/releases/tag/0.11.5.0

**Excerpt from the release notes:**

Removed `IsValid` and `TryConnect()`

The first 2 features of ElasticClient I wrote nearly three years ago which seemed like a good idea at the time. `TryConnect()` and `.IsValid()` are two confusing ways to check if your node is up, `RootNodeInfo()` now returns a mapped response of the info elasticsearch returns when you hit a node at the root (version, lucene_version etc), or you can call `client.Raw.MainGet()` or perhaps even better `client.Raw.MainHead()` or even `client.Connection.HeadSync("/")`.

You catch my drift: with so many ways of querying the root `.IsValid` and `TryConnect()` is just fluff that only introduces confusion.

Comment: So... if I wanted to ensure Elasticsearch was available before trying to send data into it, which method is most ideal? `RootNodeInfo()`? This answer seems to suggest 4 solutions, with no distinction between them.

Comment: `RootNodeInfo()` suffices, you can also use `Ping()` since [1.1.0](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/releases/tag/1.1.0). When you are using connectionpooling, NEST under the covers will ping for you the first time a node is used.